# Notes SQL 9.0 stopped working

Tags: odbc, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am trying to use IBM ODBC Driver for Notes/Domino 9.0 with Lotus Notes 9 to access distribution lists. I have successfully added a datasource (referencing a server) in ODBC Manager like so:

[image: Lotus Notes ODBC setup]

I have added the `...\IBM\Notes\` location to my `PATH`, as well as the driver's location, `...\NotesSQL\` as suggested elsewhere. However when testing the connection using ODBCTest (or other software), the following error occurs:

[image: IBM ODBC Driver crash]

I suspect this has something to do with not finding the correct `notes.ini` file (which is mentioned [here](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/notessql/3.0.2c/notessql.nsf/4d74586c8dcad500852563c000646f90/ee0e18c1e575505c85256cf4006eb316?OpenDocument)). I see there are multiple `notes.ini` files on my filesystem, so I attempted to test each one. I tried appending the location of each of these files to the beginning of `PATH` in turn, but none of these changes fixed the issue. I also noticed none of the existing `notes.ini` files are in the `...\IBM\Notes` folder with `notes.exe` where IBM suggests `notes.ini` lives by default.

How do I:

1) determine which is the correct `notes.ini`

2) get Notes SQL to recognize that `notes.ini`, assuming that's the underlying issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check the properties of the desktop/menu shortcut that starts your Notes client. The target should look like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Notes\notes.exe" "=C:\Some\Path\To\notes.ini"
```

That should be the correct notes.ini file for your installation.

Comment: Good to know - but my target variable only lists the first string, not the second.

Comment: Hmmm... Try running regedit and searching your registry for entries containing "notes.ini". With luck, all the entries that you find will point to the same one. And in general, all programs that use the Notes API should respect the command-line syntax that specifies the notes.ini location using the same equals sign syntax shown above. I'm not sure if that applies to using the ODBC drivers or not, but once you've located the correct path you can try using that syntax in the command line that starts your program.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to re-download the driver you can find the link here:

https://www-01.ibm.com/marketing/iwm/tnd/nochargesearch.jsp?cat=&q0=&pf=&k=ALL&pn=&pid=&rs=&S_TACT=104CBW71&status=Active&S_CMP=&b=&sr=1&q=IBM+ODBC+Driver+for+Notes%2FDomino&ibm-search.x=0&ibm-search.y=0